# Is there a default iOS setting for the radius of rounded buttons / views?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rounded-corners

Apple likes to change the radius of their rounded corners every so often.

Is there a system setting where one can access this?

Just like, if you always want to match Apple's system font, you can write:

```
UIFont.systemFontOfSize(UIFont.systemFontSize())
```

It wouldb be great if there was something like:

```
UIView.systemCornerRadius()
```

Is there?

**Edit:**

@BaseZen points out that the setting may be different for different UI elements--for example an Alert View may use a different radius than a standard button.

If there's an accessible system setting for *any* of these I'd be glad to hear about it.

Comment: You can;t set `cornerRadius` on `view` itself. It has to be done at `layer`. Better file a feature request to Apple!!

Comment: This is a bit vague. Rounded corners of what? Alert windows, for example?

Comment: @Santosh--thanks for pointing this out, though I already knew it. The question is about finding a system setting, not about applying it once found.

Comment: @BaseZen--I'll take anything you've got. Are you aware of a system setting that specifies the radius of the rounded corners of alert windows?